# python click sub command global option

Tags: python, python-click

```
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@click.option('--limit', type=int, default=5)
@click.option('--chunk-size', type=int, default=5)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, **kwargs):
    ctx.obj = kwargs


@cli.command()
@click.option('--url')
@click.pass_context
def index(ctx, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update(ctx.obj)
    print(kwargs)
```

How do I need to use the `--chunk-size` and `--limit` option in the index subcommand?
The effect I want `python test.py index --limit 1`

Comment: Not a solution (unfortunately), but a related discussion: https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

Pass the global options before the command:

```
./cli.py --limit 1 index --url foo
{'url': 'foo', 'limit': 1, 'chunk_size': 5}
```